# как защититься от xss атаки в url-ах,

Tags: php, javascript, url, xss

Доброго времени суток!
Есть сайт, например, http://mysite.ru/ если к пути добавить 
?d=1&search=the'"()%25alert(9925)&view=searchd то появляется окошко с надписью 9925. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Фильтровать search на сервере хотя бы через htmlspecialchars()

Comment: на сайте в форме все сделано, ничего не происходит. Такое только в урл когда вставляешь и нажимаешь энтер.

Comment: Ну кто-то же выводит данные с search на страницу, вот там и не уследили, если я вставлю это на любом другом сайте ничего не вылезет же.